# Add node at the end of a list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I want to add a node to the end of the list and this code can handle this, but when I add 3<sup>rd</sup> node it deletes the first one. The second node becomes the first and the third the second. What is the problem ?

```
struct Clothes
    {
        int item_id;
        string name_of_clothing;
        Clothes * next;
        Clothes * back;
    }*new_item, *temp, *last, *list;


int add_clothing() {
    string name_of_clothing, item_id;
    cout << "Enter ID\t: ";
    cin >> item_id;
    cout << "Enter Name of item\t: ";
    cin >> name_of_clothing;
    string new_item[2] = { item_id, name_of_clothing};
    add_New_item(new_item[0], new_item[1]);
    system("PAUSE");
    palce_and_order_menu();
    return 0;
}
void  add_New_item(string item_id, string name_of_clothing)
{
    new_item = new Clothes();
    new_item->item_id = std::stoi(item_id);
    new_item->name_of_clothing = name_of_clothing;
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        temp = last = new_item;
        cout << "\n>Element inserted in empty list\n";
    }


    else
          {
             while (temp->next != NULL){
                    temp = temp->next;          
             }
             last->next = new_item;
             new_item->back = last;
             last = new_item;
             cout << "\n>Element inserted \n";
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the `last` pointer supposed to represent?  The head of the list, or the tail?  Your overall logic seems on the right track, but if you could clarify what `temp` and `last` are supposed be doing that would be helpful.

Comment: if `temp` points to the head of the list, then modifying it in the `while`  loop and not restoring its previous value is the reason that the you lost track of the head of your list.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS yes it the head. How can I restore previous value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon your response to my comment and the limited information available about your list implementation. I would suggest the following - 
Since, you are keeping track of both the head(through `temp`) and tail(through `last`) of the list and insertion is done at the end, your function of inserting new node should look something like this -

```
void  add_New_item(string item_id, string name_of_clothing)
{
    new_item = new Clothes();
    new_item->item_id = std::stoi(item_id);
    new_item->name_of_clothing = name_of_clothing;
    new_item->back=NULL;
    new_item->next=NULL;
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        temp = last = new_item;
        cout << "\n>Element inserted in empty list\n";
    }


    else
          {

             last->next = new_item;
             new_item->back = last;
             last = new_item;
             cout << "\n>Element inserted \n";
        }
}
```

You need to change only the `last` pointer, as the  insertion is done at the end. `temp` is changed only when the list is initially empty and then the element is inserted.
 
**Note** -

- Give proper names to the variables denoting the head and tail of the
  list as improper names are causing confusion.
- While inserting a new node you were not assigning its `back` and `next` pointers to NULL or any suitable value, which could have caused undefined behavior later. That part is included in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

I think your general logic for inserting a new node should look something like this:

```
while (temp->next != NULL) {
    temp = temp->next;          
}
temp->next = new_item;
new_item->back = temp;
// last = new_item
cout << "\n>Element inserted \n";
```

It is not clear to me what `last` represents here.  Assuming you only have a HEAD pointer, then it would make sense walking down the list using a `while` loop until reaching the last node, then adding the new item there.  Most of the time, this would not change the HEAD pointer of the list.

Comment: We can iterate on this answer if it helps you.